# What is REDIRECT_KOHANA_ENV in $_SERVER environment information array

Tags: php, redirect, kohana, environment-variables

I am trying to get a PHP application based on Kohana framework working on a Linux server.

There is a problem in my `.htaccess` or application (haven't figured out yet) which is preventing the use of pretty URLs.
While I was debugging I found this in my `$_SERVER` array :

```
print_r($_SERVER);

...
[REDIRECT_KOHANA_ENV] => PRODUCTION
...
```

in my .htaccess file there is just one line to set the environment variable:

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV PRODUCTION
```

and also I am doing a redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/(this|that)/?([^/]*)$ /index.php/$1/that/ [NC,QSA,L]
```

Does anybody know how this `REDIRECT_KOHANA_ENV` is being set?

is this something related to `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's something in your htaccess causing this. Here's some details on htaccess rewrites and `REDIRECT_` constants in `$_SERVER`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php#79811